# How to pass data between controller on different files in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui

- I have a page with the Controller_1
- the Controller_1 open a modal with a different controller on a different file that we call Controller_2
- and then the Controller_2 open another modal that have a different controller on a different file that we call Controller_3

so we have:

Controller_1  --Open Modal-->  Controller_2  --Open Modal-->  Controller_3

when i close the modal with the Controller_3, I want to pass a value to the Controller_1.

my code:

Controller_1 open a modal with the Controller_2

```
app.controller("Controller_1", ['$scope', '$http', '$modal', 
function ($scope, $http, $modal) {

$scope.openModal_1 = function () {

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: '/SomeFolder/FileWithController_2',
        controller: 'Controller_2',
    });
}

}]);
```

Controller_2 open a modal with the Controller_3

```
app.controller("Controller_2", ['$scope', '$http', '$modalInstance', '$modal',
function ($scope, $http, $modalInstance, $modal) {

$scope.SaveSomething = function () {

            $http.post(url, obj)
                .success(function (data) {
                        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                        templateUrl: '/SomeFolder/FileWithController_3',
                        controller: 'Controller_3',
                        }
                    });

                }).error(function () {

                });
        };
    }]);
```

Controller_3 save something then close and pass some data to the Controller_1

```
app.controller("Controller_3", ['$scope', '$http', '$modalInstance',
function ($scope, $http, $modalInstance) {        

   $scope.SaveSomething = function () {

                    $http.post(url, obj)
                        .success(function (data) {

                             ... pass some code to Controller_1 and close this modal.

                            });

                        }).error(function () {

                        });
                };
            }]);
```

Assuming that everything is working fine and all I want to do is passing some data from Controller_3 to Controller_1.

My question is:
How I can pass the data from Controller_3 to Controller_1?

I already tried pass the $scope when I open the modal as follows:

```
//from Controller_1 to Controller_2

     var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                templateUrl: '/SomeFolder/FileWithController_2',
                controller: 'Controller_2',
                scope: $scope,
            });
```

in this case it work only for the Controller_2, so any modification on $scope will affect the Controller_1 but it is not working the same way if i do the same for Controller_3

I tried $emit and $on but it do not work too because they are not parent and child like this:

```
<div ng-controller="ParentCtrl">
    <div ng-controller="ChildCtrl"></div>
</div>
```

they are complete different controllers in different files.

Comment: Did you try passing and receiving events with $rootScope? I think that is a valid use of $rootScope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See $parent in [Angular doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope)

Declare your modal instance,

```
 var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: '/SomeFolder/FileWithController_3',
            controller: 'Controller_3',
            scope: $scope.$parent,
        });
```

So you can basically call a method or edit a property from controller_1 in your controller_3.

```
app.controller("Controller_3", ['$scope', '$http', '$modalInstance',
function ($scope, $http, $modalInstance) {        

app.controller("Controller_3", ['$scope', '$http', '$modalInstance',
function ($scope, $http, $modalInstance) {        

   $scope.SaveSomething = function () {    
      $http.post(url, obj)
           .success(function (data) {
                $scope.$parent.modethodToCall(data);
           })
           .error(function () {});
   };
}]);
```

I think you have to add another $parent because $modal create it's own child $scope. If someone can confirm ?

I personnaly won't recommand to use parent properties/methods. In my projects i create modal instance with params and return an object on modal closure. (See $modal in [Angular ui doc](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal))

```
$modalInstance.close(data);
```

Comment: Hi @jbigman

I tried both ways:

If I use: $scope.$parent.$parent.modethodToCall(data), i can't find the methods i want to change on controller_1. If I use ...  scope: $scope.$parent, .. , I find the methods, but the changes do not make any effect on controller_1. I will keep testing and see if i can find a way to make it work with you suggestion.

thanks.

Comment: Hi @jbigman, It is working now, I'm passing scope: $scope.$parent when i open the modal with controller_3 and $scope.$parent.modethodToCall(data); to call my function.

Thanks you very much.

Comment: I edited the answer with your working solution. + commented about using modal parameters and return value on closure.

Answer (score 1):

You may use **events** and listen to these events.

Follow bellow an example:

```
app.controller('controller1', ['$scope','$rootScope', controller1]);

function controller1($scope, $rootScope){
    $scope.$on('informController1', informController1);

    function informController1(information){
        //information displayed on the controller 1 related view
        $scope.ctrl1Information = information;
    }
}

app.controller('controller2', ['$scope','$rootScope', controller2]);

function controller2($scope, $rootScope){
    //controller2 logic
}

app.controller('controller3', ['$scope','$rootScope', controller3]);

function controller3($scope, $rootScope){
    $scope.$on('informController3', informController3);

    function informController3(information){
        //information displayed on the controller 3 related view
        $scope.ctrl3Information = information;
    }

    function closeModal(){
        //close modal code...

        $rootScope.$broadcast('informController1', $scope.ctrl3Information);
    }
}
```

*For this approach to work, you have to make sure the controller is loaded when the event was triggered.*